# VBA - How to check if a String is a valid hex color code?

Tags: vba, excel, exception, error-handling

To prevent errors, I need to check if a String retrieved from a custom input box is not a valid hex color code. So far I found various solutions for other languages, but none for VBA.

Working on the following code, giving a not hex value input will cause a run time error. That's critical to my project, since I am working on a protected sheet.

```
Public Function HexWindow(MyCell As String, Description As String, Caption As String)
    Dim myValue As Variant
    Dim priorValue As Variant
    priorValue = Range(MyCell).Value
    myValue = InputBox(Description, Caption, Range(MyCell).Value)
    Range(MyCell).Value = myValue
    If myValue = Empty Then
        Range(MyCell).Value = priorValue
    End If
    tHex = Mid(Range(MyCell).Text, 6, 2) & Mid(Range(MyCell).Text, 4, 2) & Mid(Range(MyCell).Text, 2, 2)
    Range(MyCell).Interior.Color = WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(tHex)
End Function
```

How can I set a condition that recognizes a value not being in the format of "#" & 6 characters from 0-9 and A-F in any case?

Comment: Don't have time to add any code right now but I would investigate regular expressions.

Comment: What do you mean by "regular expressions"? I have to add I am kind of new to programming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple ways to do this.  The easiest way is with a regular expression:

```
'Requires reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions x.x
Private Function IsHex(inValue As String) As Boolean
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "^#[0-9A-F]{1,6}$"
        .IgnoreCase = True                'Optional depending on your requirement
        IsHex = .Test(inValue)
    End With
End Function
```

If for some reason that doesn't appeal to you, you could also take advantage of VBA's permissive casting of hex strings to numbers:

```
Private Function IsHex(ByVal inValue As String) As Boolean
    If Left$(inValue, 1) <> "#" Then Exit Function
    inValue = Replace$(inValue, "#", "&H")
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim hexValue As Long
    hexValue = CLng(inValue)  'Type mismatch if not a number.
    If Err.Number = 0 And hexValue < 16 ^ 6 Then
        IsHex = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Locké - See the edit - the expression should have anchors.

Comment: ***Actually***, during my tests, the RegEx method took about **50x as long** as the permissive casting method!

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions for this. First you must go to `Tools-->References`in the VBA editor (alt-f11) and make sure this library is checked

```
Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
```

Then you could modify this sample code to meet your needs

```
Sub RegEx_Tester()
Set objRegExp_1 = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegExp_1.Global = True
objRegExp_1.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp_1.Pattern = "#[a-z0-9]{6}"
strToSearch = "#AAFFDD"
Set regExp_Matches = objRegExp_1.Execute(strToSearch)
If regExp_Matches.Count = 1 Then
    MsgBox ("This string is a valid hex code.")
End If
End Sub
```

The main feature of this code is this

```
objRegExp_1.Pattern = "#[a-z,A-Z,0-9]{6}"
```

It says that you will accept a string that has a `#` followed by any 6 characters that are a combination of upper case or lower case strings or numbers 0-9. `strToSearch` is just the string you are testing to see if it is a valid color hex string. I believe this should help you.

I should credit [this site](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-regex/). You may want to check it out if you want a crash course on regular expressions. They're great once you learn how to use them.